# Mac OS X: Scrollbar is sometimes white-transparent and sometimes black-transparent

Tags: css, macos, scrollbar

I wondered why the scrollbar on Mac OS X is sometimes white-transparent and sometimes black-transparent, if you set "Show scroll bars" to "When scrolling" in the general settings. This happens for all browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera).

Answer (score 10):

The reason for this is, that Mac OS X sets the color of the scrollbar dependent on the background-color of your `body` or (if you haven't set a background-color or use `transparent`) your `html` tag.

- dark background color → white-transparent scrollbar
- light background color → black-transparent scrollbar

One possible and *hacky* solution is avoiding setting a background-color and instead use a base64-encoded 1px colored gif as a background-image. *gosh*

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can simply use `color-scheme: dark` on your html / body element to force a dark scrollbar. Same with `color-scheme: light`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme